# Code simplification

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-structures

I am new to R and just going through some coding examples. Someone had posted the below mentioned codes. It seems they used dput() to post the structure of the variable holding the data.

```
df1 <- structure(list(keyword = c("cat", "dog", "pig", "crow", "pigeon", "hawk", "catfish", "carp"), 
                    category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")), .Names = c("Keyword", "Category"), 
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))

df2 <- structure(list(description = structure(c(2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L,3L),
                                              .Label = c("dogged dog", "false cat", "hawkward carp", "sad catfish", "shady pigeon", "smiling pig"), class = "factor")), 
                 .Names = "description", row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can anyone help me to understand how are these above mentioned data structures exactly defined?(lists,dataframes, factors?)

How are these df1 and df2 actually defined, please help to decode them.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate 李哲源 Zheyuan Li's comment:

You can see the contents of each with

```
> df1
  Keyword Category
1     cat        A
2     dog        A
3     pig        A
4    crow        B
5  pigeon        B
6    hawk        B
7 catfish        C
8    carp        C
> df2
    description
1     false cat
2   smiling pig
3  shady pigeon
4    dogged dog
5   sad catfish
6 hawkward carp
```

and their structures with `str`

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Keyword : chr  "cat" "dog" "pig" "crow" ...
 $ Category: chr  "A" "A" "A" "B" ...
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ description: Factor w/ 6 levels "dogged dog","false cat",..: 2 6 5 1 4 3
```

leading to the description "They are both data.frame, with columns of `df1` being character strings, but that of `df2` being factor."

It would be repetition, but you could check this with `class` as in

```
> class(df1)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(df1$Keyword)
[1] "character"
> class(df1$Category)
[1] "character"
> class(df2)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(df2$description)
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: Thank you very much